# PHP PDO Parameters from a function returned array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I've got a function written that runs a query based on parameters passed to the function.

I can't seem to figure out why doing the following returns a result:

```
function test($function_returned_array)
{
    $variable = 'Hello World';
    $sql = 'SELECT `name`, `pid`
            FROM `products`
            WHERE `name` IN (?)';
    $found = $this->db->get_array($sql, $variable);
}
```

While this doesn't return any results:

```
function test2($function_returned_array)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT `name`, `pid`
            FROM `products`
            WHERE `name` IN (?)';
    $found = $this->db->get_array($sql, $function_returned_array[0]);
}
```

$function_returned_array[0] is also equal to 'Hello World'. Shouldn't they both return the same results?

When I echo the values of $variable and $function_returned_array[0], they are both 'Hello World'

Here's the relevant parts of my PDO wrapper:

```
public function query(&$query, $params)
{
    $sth = $this->_db->prepare($query);

    if(is_null($params))
    {
        $sth->execute();
    }
    else if(is_array($params))
    {
        $sth->execute($params);
    }
    else
    {
        $sth->execute(array($params));
    }

    $this->_rows = $sth->rowCount();
    $this->_counter++;
    return $sth;
}

public function get_array(&$query, $params, $style = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
{
    $q = $this->query($query, $params);
    return $q->fetchAll($style);
}
```

I'm using PHP 5.3.5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this code lacks debugging. And asks strangers to debug it mentally. I'd -1 it but refrain from that just for sake of having an *PDO wrapper* - a thing almost never seen on this "enthusiast programmers" site

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it was clear enough :( I'll edit it a bit more.

Comment: Why are you passing the query string as a reference?

Comment: why such a complex code? why you are using a function? Why such a complex way of passing a scalar variable - via array member? why can't you pass your hello world as a scalar already?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, the above is a condensed version of the code. The query was more like WHERE `name` IN (?, ?, ?)'. The parameter passed to query() was the entire array.

Comment: I'm just asking for help, you don't have to be so hostile.

Comment: I am not being hostile. I am just voting this question to close.

Answer (score 0):

i have witnessed the same problem in PDO. PDO only accepts the local variable for parametrized query and not by reference or argument not sure why though.

the workaround for it can be.

```
function test2($function_returned_array)
{
    $variable = $function_returned_array[0];
    $sql = 'SELECT `name`, `pid`
            FROM `products`
            WHERE `name` IN (?)';
    $found = $this->db->get_array($sql, $variable);
}
```

**Update:**

You are doing it wrong. you have to Use PDO prepare() statement for parameterized query whereas i see you are using the PDO query() directly into your get_query() method.

you should use `query()` method only if you don't want to pass any parameter to the query.and according to php documentation here is the syntax

```
PDOStatement PDO::query ( string $statement )
```

the second argument you are trying to pass is wrong.

so instead use `prepare()` method, and here is the link.

http://in.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this as well and it still returned different results from that of test(). Although, when I manually set the value of $function_returned_array[1] in test2() it worked. Any more ideas?

Comment: hold on i think i got your problem, you are doing it wrong way. ill update my post with the explaination.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using the prepare() method in $sth = $this->_db->prepare($query). I'll look over everything again though. There must be something else wrong with my code!

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, the problem was that $function_returned_array[0] and $variable did not really equal the same thing. $function_returned_array[0] needed to be passed through an html_entity_decode().